# Aws Inventory list of resources using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-resource-explorer

```
import boto3
import csv
from io import StringIO
import time
 
def search_all_resources():
    client = boto3.client('resource-explorer-2')
    all_resources = []
 
    # Initialize with a dummy NextToken to start the first page
    next_token = None
    retries = 0
   
    while True:
        try:
            if next_token:
                # Fetch resources for the current page
                response = client.search(
                    MaxResults=123,
                    NextToken=next_token,
                    QueryString=' ',
                    ViewArn='arn'
                )
       
                if 'Resources' in response:
                    all_resources.extend(response['Resources'])
                    print('in next token loop')
               
                # Check if there are more pages
                next_token = response.get('NextToken')
               
            else:
                response = client.search(
                    MaxResults=123,
                    QueryString=' ',
                    ViewArn='arn'
                )
       
                if 'Resources' in response:
                    all_resources.extend(response['Resources'])
       
            # If no exception occurred, reset retries
            retries = 0
            break
 
        except client.exceptions.ThrottlingException as e:
            if retries >= 5:  # Max retries
                print("Max retries exceeded. Exiting.")
                raise e
            else:
                retries += 1
                delay = 2 ** retries
                print(f"ThrottlingException. Retrying in {delay} seconds.")
                time.sleep(delay)
 
    return all_resources
   
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Search for all resources and fetch paginated results
    all_resources = search_all_resources()
   
    # Print and write to CSV
    if all_resources:
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_buffer, fieldnames=all_resources[0].keys())
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerows(all_resources)
        csv_data = csv_buffer.getvalue()
   
        # Specify your S3 bucket and key
        s3_bucket = 'test-bucket'
        s3_key = 'path/to/aws_resources.csv'
   
        # Upload CSV data to S3
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.put_object(Body=csv_data, Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
   
        print(f"Successfully uploaded CSV to S3: s3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_key}")
    else:
        print("No resources found.")
```

we tried to get Inventory it means list of all resources from aws console but we were able to get only 123 of them .

Using above code we are getting Throttling exception for fetching the resources, also it works only once. we are unable to fetch more than 123 resources, our aim is to fetch all resources available in resource explorer weather it might be 500-100, the code should fetch and store in csv file in s3 bucket

Comment: you have an unconditional `break`, but you should probably use a paginator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have `MaxResults=123` which is working fine I presume that is why you are getting 123 but you also have `break` in the same level as the if statement which means your while loop will run only once.
That’s why you have 123

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. As mentioned in other answer, you have an unconditional break which will stop your loop.
2. You do next_token = response.get('NextToken') only in the branch where next_token already exists, meaning you will not populate `next_token` on your first go. I would change the way you go through them to getting the list first, and then looping through if `NextToken` exists. Something like this:

   ```
   response = client.search(
       MaxResults=123,
       QueryString=' ',
       ViewArn='arn' 
   ) 
   while 'NextToken' in response:
       response = client.search(
           MaxResults=123,
           NextToken=response.get('NextToken'),
           QueryString=' ',
           ViewArn='arn'
       )
       if 'Resources' in response:
           all_resources.extend(response['Resources'])
   ```

Comment: @Anjumaara If that worked, it would be nice to mark it as a solution :) and add a vote to it